# codeigniter foreach not displaying all records in table

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, chat

Hi I am able to retrieve data from a specific table using codeigniter ajax but i don't see everything.

It's simply a chat system I implemented allowing users to send messages to one another.

Everytime a new record is inserted, the latest record does not show up but the previous ones do.

Please see my code attached with this.

Thank you.

**Controller - Chats.php**

```
public function ajax_get_chat_messages()
{
    echo $this->_get_chat_messages();
}

public function _get_chat_messages()
{
    $recipient = $this->input->post('recipient');

    $chat = $this->Chats_model->get_chat_messages($recipient);
    if($chat->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $c_html = '<ul>';
        foreach($chat->result() as $cht)
        {
            $c_html  .= '<li>'.$cht->username.'</li>';
            $c_html  .= '<p>'.$cht->chat_message_content.'</p><hr><br>';
        }
        $c_html .= '</ul>';

        $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $c_html);
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

**JS - Chat2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () { get_chat_messages();}, 2500)

    function get_chat_messages()
    {
        $.post(base_url + "user/chats/ajax_get_chat_messages", {recipient: recipient}, function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'ok')
            {
                $("div#view").html(data.content);
            } else
            {
                //there was an error do something 
            }
        }, "json");
    }


    /*function get_chat_messages() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: 'json',
     url: base_url +"user/chats/ajax_get_chat_messages",
     data: {recipient: recipient}, // pass it as POST parameter
     success: function(data){   

     $("div#view").html(data);
     console.log(data);
     }
     });
     } */

    get_chat_messages();
});
```

model - Chats_model.php

```
public function get_chat_messages($recipient)
{
    $session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM chat_messages cm JOIN users u on u.user_id = cm.user_id where cm.user_id = $session and cm.recipient = $recipient or cm.user_id = $recipient and cm.recipient = $session ORDER BY cm.chat_message_id ASC ";
    $result = $this->db->query($query, array($recipient));
    return $result;
}
```

Image also attached

[image: Chat image]

Comment: Probably a typo when you copied in the code but, the line with `setinterval` does not have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. You're certain it is not a problem with posting the  new message?

Comment: I fixed it, it was an issue with posting. Thanks all